# Reset datepicker view using dl-date-time-picker in angular 8

Tags: angular8, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker component in a bootstrap modal. I'm using Angular 8 and have used Dalelotts dl-date-time-picker component.

I need to reset the view of date picker whenever user closes the modal i.e. if user selects date but not time and closes the modal, when reopens the modal datetime picker should display from date selection view. But in my case it is showing from where I left off. I tried setting the startView of this datetimepicker component to 'day' on modal close button callback event but did not fix my problem. Any idea to fix this?

I am using something like:

```
<dl-date-time-picker [(startView)]="startView" [(ngModel)]="enteredDate (change)="dateSelected($event)" [selectFilter]="datePickerFilter"> </dl-date-time-picker>
```

This is my sample working example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/dalelotts-angular-date-time-picker?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event of type (Click) in the button "Ok" and trigger an method that restart the input to an specific date or set to a empty string